# Pegar id ordenado de uma lista que contem labels dentro dela

Tags: lista

Como faço para pegar a ordem dos id de cada um dos labels que estão nessa lista.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="">
    <p>SUAS OPÇÕES</p>
    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-default">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: olá, precisa esclarecer melhor...  quer fazer isso no front ou backend? já tentou alguma coisa? explique o que já fez e se possível coloque o código na pergunta

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Não como fazer preciso pegar a lista no backend, estou usando aspnet c#